# Searching a set with specific element

Tags: notation

I am from computer science and I need some mathematics help.

I have a power set of some type. I need to search a set which consists some element in it. For example a power set is $bank = \{\{1,2\},\{2,2\},\{3,3\},\{4,4\}\}$ in which first element is unique say account number. I want to search set that has first element 1. Let's say I input 1, it return $\{1,2\}$ i.e. first set. If I search 3 it return $\{3,3\}$.

Does mathematics have some built-in operator such as interaction, or generalized intersection^

Comment: Note that a _set_ in mathematics does not remember any ordering of its elements, so $\{1,2\}$ is the same set at $\{2,1\}$, and $\{2,2\}$ is just a roundabout way to write $\{2\}$.

Comment: It smells like what you're really looking for might be something like [relational algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) (which is more of a CS thing than a math thing).

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no such operator as far as I'm aware.
What's more - it's more important if the programming language, which you're using, has something close to your needs.